# Kotlin using getter for read-only variable

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, robolectric

Is there any reason we use get() for val variable?

I think following code is not necessary

```
private val context: Context get() = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

So I changed this to

```
private val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

What would be difference using get() for read-only variable?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with two different ways to declare properties:

**Property with a backing field**

If you declare a property `context` and assign it like this:

```
private val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

you created a [property with backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields).

`ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()` is evaluated once, when the class is instantiated. Since `context` is immutable (`val`) each time the same value is returned (which was assigned by the function call).

**Property without a backing field**

If you declare `context` like this

```
private val context: Context get() = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

you created a property without a backing field. `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()`  will be evaluated each time you access `context`. The value returned by the [getter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) can change depending if the forwarded call of the function returns something different.

**What to use?**

So, it depends on your use case, but in this particular case I would recommend you to go with the property without a backing field variant for two reasons:

1. you cannot be sure `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()` will always return the same value, at least the documentation does not mention that explicitely
2. forwarding the function call won't have a major performance impact

Answer (score 1):

**For getter no need to define get() but setter case set is required.**

Since Kotlin 1.1, you can omit the property type if it can be inferred from the getter:

```
val isEmpty get() = this.size == 0  // has type Boolean
```

If you need to change the visibility of an accessor or to annotate it, but don't need to change the default implementation, you can define the accessor without defining its body:

```
var setterVisibility: String = "abc"
private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
var setterVisibility: String = "abc"
private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
```

​
for more details refer [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question (except for the link at the end).

Answer (score 0):

The link given by IntelliJ Amiya in the comment contains all necessary information, but to answer your question in particular:

`get() = ...` will call `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()` each time it's accessed; just `= ...` will call it once and store, and then return the stored value when accessed. Which one you want or whether they are effectively equivalent (because e.g. the body always returns the same value and fast enough) depends on context.